# AngularJs - ReferenceError: errors is not defined - Reloading the page solves the error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a very weird problem that only occurs from time to time. Sometimes when I load my page I get the following error in console. I can then reload the site and everything works normal again.

```
angular.js:12520 ReferenceError: errors is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:4994), <anonymous>:1:13)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:4994
    at Function.globalEval (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:5005)
    at init.domManip (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:28160)
    at init.append (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:25581)
    at init.<anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:27127)
    at Function.access (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:6690)
    at init.html (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:26701)
    at https://example.com/app1//Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:27884 <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I don't know exactly where the error happens but I have a `ng-form` where I track errors that I think is the source. The weird thing is that it works most of the time and if the error occurs all I have to do is reload the page and it starts working again. Has anyone experienced this before?

```
<ng-form name="validationForm">

    <ng-form name="companyDetails">
        <!-- inputs and other controls here -->
    </ng-form>

    <ng-form name="paymentInformation">
        <!-- inputs and other controls here -->    
    </ng-form>

    <div ng-repeat="(key, errors) in validationForm.companyDetails.$error track by $index" class="text-muted">
        <p><b>Wrong input in company details:</b></p>
        <p style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-repeat="e in errors">
            - {{e.$name}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, errors) in validationForm.paymentInformation.$error track by $index" class="text-muted">
        <p>
            <b>
                Wrong input in payment information:
                <script>console.log(errors)</script>:
            </b>
        </p>
        <p style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-repeat="e in errors">
            - {{e.$name}}
        </p>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

Comment: Post the JS that drives the markup as well.

Comment: It seems like errors is `undefined` on the very first page load. You need to make sure that it is not `undefined` before triggering `ng-repeat` on it.

Comment: Can you try by removing nested <ng-form> from your view. Flow content, but with no form element descendants -  For reference https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

Comment: Hi. even am facing same issue. did u get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a native javascript `console.log()` like this, inside the loop, even if you've put `errors` in your `ng-repeat`, js outside of Angular might not know what it is.

This is why you have `errors is undefined`

```
<b>
    Wrong input in payment information:
    <script>console.log(errors)</script>:
</b>
```

One possible solution to this would be:

**JS**

```
//Put this in the relevant controller
$scope.logError = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<b>
    Wrong input in payment information:
    {{logError(errors)}}
</b>
```

This way you will pass the errors back to Angular, and the value of the variable shouldn't be unknown anymore.